# How to enable/disable BsMultiSelect

Tags: javascript, bsmultiselect

I am trying to use [BsMultiSelect](https://github.com/DashboardCode/BsMultiSelect).

How can I manually enable/disable a select menu?

I was able to successfully disable the menu like so

```
// remove all options
removeOptions(select); 

// disable the select element
select.setAttribute('disabled', true); 

// update the data since all options were removed
select.updateData();

// update the appearance of the menu since it is now disabled
select.updateAppearance();
```

Then I tried to enable it like this which did not work

```
// add new options to the select element
addOptions(select);

// enable the select element
select.removeAttribute('disabled');


// update the data since new options were added
select.updateData();

// update the appearance of the menu since it is now enabled
select.updateAppearance();
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I had an identical problem and solved it by the build-in option getDisabled from bsMultiSelect, which requires either true or false.

I then used  `$('#yourMultiSelectOption').attr('custom-data-attr', false/true).bsMultiSelect("UpdateDisabled")` to first change the attribute to the desired option and then manually trigger an update of the bsMultiSelect.

```js
$(#yourMultiSelectOption).bsMultiSelect({
    getDisabled: function () {
                     return $("#yourMultiSelectOption").attr('custom-data-attr') === 'true';
                 },
    [other options...]
})
```